# Using Material-ui custom theme with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, higher-order-components

I have Material-ui and redux all set up in and working, however redux has you use connect with higher order components:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);
```

while the Material-ui documentation has you do something similar:

```
export default muiThemeable()(ComponentName);
```

How would you combine the theme with the redux export to get them to export or work together?

Comment: Doesn't this work `const T = muiThemeable()(C)` and `export default connect(stateToProps)(T)`?

Comment: I still haven't quite got it from that, but I think that is the right path and probably an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: `connect` takes a bunch of stuff and _one_ component and will return another component. `muiThemeable` takes a bunch of stuff and _one_ component and returns another component. Think of them as ordinary functions. You call first one and then pass the resulting component to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [compose multiple Higher Order Components](https://medium.com/dailyjs/react-composing-higher-order-components-hocs-3a5288e78f55):

```
export default muiThemeable()(connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName));
```

An HOC takes a component (and possibly other arguments) and returns another component. So, the return value of an HOC is a valid argument for another HOC.